# Join migration tables with Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I would like to get a new table from two migrations tables:

In migrations folder, I create these tables:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='GeneratedReport',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('created', django_extensions.db.fields.CreationDateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='created')),
                ('modified', django_extensions.db.fields.ModificationDateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='modified')),
                ('print_date', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('s3_url', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True)),
                ('error', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=600, null=True)),
                ('size', models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ('-modified', '-created'),
                'get_latest_by': 'modified',
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),


migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Subscriber',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('created', django_extensions.db.fields.CreationDateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='created')),
                ('modified', django_extensions.db.fields.ModificationDateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='modified')),
                ('userid', models.IntegerField(unique=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, null=True)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=100)),
                ('contribution', models.IntegerField()),
                ('signupdate', models.DateTimeField()),
                ('user_lang', models.CharField(blank=True, choices=[('en', 'English'), ('fr', 'French'), ('es', 'Spanish'), ('jp', 'Japanese')], max_length=3, null=True)),
                ('subscribed', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('_weather_unit', models.CharField(blank=True, choices=[('us', 'Imperial'), ('si', 'SI'), (None, 'Automatic')], max_length=3, null=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ('-modified', '-created'),
                'get_latest_by': 'modified',
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
```

In models.py:

```
class Subscriber(TimeStampedModel):
    userid = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    contribution = models.IntegerField()
    signupdate = models.DateTimeField()
    user_lang = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES)
    subscribed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    _weather_unit = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True, choices=WEATHER_UNIT_CHOICES)

class GeneratedReport(TimeStampedModel):
    report = models.ForeignKey(ReportType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    print_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    s3_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    error = models.CharField(max_length=600, null=True, blank=True)
    size = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Now, I would like to get a new table with these fields:

```
user
month
year
s3_link
```

I'm not too sure about what should I do in the `migrations` folder and in the `models.py` script. Do I have to create a new model? And how exactly is made the connection between models.py and migration with Django.

The final goal is to get, for a given userid, every s3_link with an HTTP method

Comment: do you want to join these table to get the data ?

Comment: yes in order to get every s3 links per user

Comment: I didn't see any relation between `Subscriber` and `GeneratedReport`. so, how can we get `s3_url` related to user ?

Comment: In migrations, both contains the field `id`

Comment: `id` is not a relation. Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: Where `user`, `month`, and `year` come from?